# many to many relationship is making problems in grails

Tags: mongodb, grails

I have to domain class which they have many to many relationship between them. Like the following the first class

```
class HealthCenter {
    List <FieldOfficer> fieldOfficers
    static hasMany = [fieldOfficers:FieldOfficer]
    static belongTo = FieldOfficer
}
```

The second class

```
class FieldOfficer{
    List<HealthCenter> healthCenters
    static hasMany = [healthCenters : HealthCenter]
}
```

How I can access every values inside the `healthCenters` assigned to `fieldOfficers` other than the following

```
List<HealthCenter> healthCenters1
    healthCenters1 = fieldOfficers.healthCenters
    healthCenters1.each{i ->
    print i
}
```